# Edited cruise work for NetLogo 5.3 version, background image is not getting displayed

Tags: gis, netlogo

I replaced the code whereever it was needed to for NetLogo 5.3 latest version. Whole code is too long to paste here and since there is no syntax error, I attached the runing interface of this edited model. At run time the background image was not there and turtles rotate at the same position without any displacement.

[image]

The last part of the code reports a big combination of digits and it is said that this "can be removed if data file used for map".

Further, I replaced the statement: 'set datfile datfile + ".dat" ' with 'set datfile word datfile ".dat" '
How to get the background image and make the model work. Is there any option to get the new version of cruise work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it does not run correctly, but it runs without error?  It sounds like you're almost there.  Does the way it's running make sense given the incorrect background?  Do you have the data file, and did you correctly set the global `datfile` to the name of this file?  If not, are the hard-coded numbers being read correctly from the string or list they are in?

Comment: Yes sir it is not running correctly and I am unable to understand its sense without background image. Even, I don't have the datfile and I don't know how to get it and set it globally. The actual background image can be referred in the paper "The Integration of Agent-Based Modelling and Geographical Information for Geospatial Simulation" by Andrew T. crooks and  Christian J.E. Castle,  Page number 241 Figure 12.4 (c). Just for the referrence.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to sort your patches before setting the colors:

```
(foreach sort patches patchcolors [ask ?1 [set pcolor ?2]])
```

Once you do this, the model should work just fine.  Please consider posting the fix back to the Community.

Comment: Thank you sir, But I already had done that, When i asked about "foreach statement not working" in one of my questions.

Comment: sir what is fix back? and how to post it in the community.

Comment: @AbhaTrivedi When I sort the patches inside the foreach statement, the display is fine and the model works.  This along with the other change (updated syntax) is the "fix" to the model.  The model is a Community model, so I suggested that you post an updated model to the Community, once you are done fixing it.

Comment: Editing of cruise work  does not implement any new idea just few of the codes I rewrote for the new version as it had many old style code lines, then also I can upload this work in netlogo community.

Comment: @AbhaTrivedi  Good question.  I see the authors neglected to specify a license for the code, and I do not see a default license specified on the website.  Let me get back to you.

Comment: @AbhaTrivedi Guerin wrote me that the code is released under the MIT License, so it can be freely modified and distributed.  You can add the following line to the credits section (along with a note saying what you changed):
MIT License Copyright (C) 2004, Owen Densmore, Stephen Guerin and RedfishGroup.